# Tensorflow: train two layer streams separately?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Let's assume I have a convolutional neural network which should predict two different (semantically) things out of images which can be classified in a N-dimensional output each. So my network looks like this:

```
# architecture 

             input
          (RGB images)
               |
          conv_layer 1
               |
             .....
               |
          conv_layer n
               |
        _______________
        |              |
      fc1_x          fc1_y    <-- fully-connected layer 1
        |              |
      fc2_x          fc2_y    <-- fully-connected layer 2 / output
   (output_x)     (output_y)
```

`output_x` is a vector of dimension `(1, 1000)`, therefore predicting over 1000 classes. `output_y` is a vector of dimension `(1, 500)`, therefore predicting over 500 classes.

The classes in x and y are semantically related, so they are *not* one-hot encoded. Instead, a normal distribution around the real class is fitted in the training vectors.

With every training step I am minimizing the cross entropy error like this:

```
train_step_x = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cross_entropy_x)
train_step_y = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cross_entropy_y)
```

So I'm calculating different cross entropy errors for `output_x` and `output_y`.

Up to now I am satisfied with the (training) results of the network. However, the network architecture is not final. It will get bigger and eventually deeper and the training data set will be several orders of magnitude bigger as it is by now.

**My question is**: Is this a reasonable network architecture? Or is it considered rather a *bad design*?

**Is Tensorflow really training the two streams separately**? Or are my two AdamOptimizers per learning step *bad design* and am I just getting "magically" good looking results although my architecture wouldn't be considered "good" for this problem?

I thought two *different* fully-connected "streams" for x and y data/classes would be reasonable for an architecture which should predict between two different "sets" of classes.

Comment: What happens if you use one training step - `train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cross_entropy_x + cross_entropy_y)`.  I expect it is much faster and gets a similar result.

Comment: Will test it. I thought combining the error doesnt make that much sense since the x and y classes/vectors have  nothing in common semantically.

Comment: @user728291 with combining `cross_entropy_x` and `cross_entropy_y` via adding them and having only one minimizing step the calculation indeed is *a lot* faster - however, the results are worse. They look *mixed* somehow and it takes a lot more epochs to get good predictions.

Comment: Both training and test results worse? Also, is cross entropy the mean across a batch or just the sum of cross entropy?

Comment: It's the sum. The results look similar but it takes much more epochs to get there for both, training and tests results.

Comment: Then minimize (cross_entropy_x + cross_entropy_y) / 2.  If they were means I don't think it would matter but because they are sums, adding the two is changing your effective learning rate.  Similar impact to doubling the batch size.

Comment: @user728291 even if they were means just adding them would be like doubling the learning rate.

Comment: @mdaoust - good point.  Reflecting on this more I think it is more accurate to say adding the losses doubles the learning rate of the shared layers while dividing each loss by half and then adding halves the learning rate of the unshared layers.  My comment on mean cross entropy was incorrect though.  So combining two minimise steps to one probably requires optimizing learning rate.

Comment: Ok, so halving the `cross_entropy_x + cross_entropy_y` converges faster than without halving it but still it needs way more epochs than training it separately like in my initial post. It is hard to really tell what the accuracy is like, because I haven't implemented a reasonable solution for this for my architecture but the distributions and the error rates for greyscaled images for example look good with about 1000 to 1500 epochs with my initial post's solution. Adding the cross entropies takes like 3000-4000 epochs while halving took about 2000-3000 epochs to produce good results.